# HTML5 - store data locally without php

Tags: xml, html, local-storage

I need a little help. I have a kiosk-like app, programmed in html that needs to store user statistics and contact(if provided) without php.

I've been reading the w3c documentation about the localStorage feature in HTML5. Does this feature store information in any local file? Is this a replacement to store data within a XML file?

What is the best way to store information locally?

thanks!

Comment: I've found that JSON content can be read to change JS values with [this code from tutorials point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_ajax_example.htm)

Now i just need to reverse the process. Instead of reading and changing the js values, i need to change the json values. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

localStorage and sessionStorage are a way to use a KV database that most current browsers support, you can use it to store small datasets, its very simple to use you get and set values based on keys. For your use case I think it fits perfectly.

- localStorage persists data between sessions
- sessionStorage persists data from session.

You have to be careful, because it can be cleaned by the user just like cookies.

Comment: I've been exploring the feature and it's pretty straight forward. However, i can't figure out a way to output it to a file. I've been looking at JSON in alternative